# Why is $\left\{ n\in \mathbb{N}:n^2 \right\}$ nonsense, $ $ but $\left\{ n^2: n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Why is $\left\{ n\in \mathbb{N}:n^2   \right\}$ nonsense,  $ $ but $\left\{ n^2: n\in \mathbb{N}   \right\}$ correct?

From my understanding, $\left\{ n\in \mathbb{N}:n^2   \right\}$ should be read as:
*"The set of natural numbers such that each natural number is multiplied to itself."*

What's wrong with this?

Why is it not equivalent to $\left\{ n^2: n\in \mathbb{N}   \right\}$? $ $ which is read as:
*"The set of $n^2$'s such that $n$ is a natural number."*

Comment: The convention is that what's to the right of the colon is a proposition.

Comment: As far as I know,it's just not generally accepted notation. There's nothing MATHEMATICALLY wrong with it. It's kind of like saying please either before or after a request-technically,either should be ok, but the rules of grammar in sentence construction say the former is correct.

Comment: "The set of natural numbers such that each natural number is multiplied to itself" is empty. Because that's not what natural numbers do. "The set of $n^2$'s such that $n$ is a natural number." on the other hand makes sense.

Comment: @HansEngler Well, that depends on how you define the natural numbers, doesn't it? If we accept it as a Peano system only, then yes,you're absolutely right. If we define it as a the following ordered quadruple:$\mathbb N $  = ( P, $\leq$,+,x) where P is the Peano system, $\leq$ is the linear ordering relation and +,x are the usual binary arithmetic operations, then no.

Comment: So it's mere convention, but under some definition of $\mathbb{N}$, $\left\{ n\in \mathbb{N}:n^2   \right\}$ has meaning, but not the one I expected?

Comment: @Stephen even PEDMAS/BODMAS/BEDMAS is a convention in that case it's so that you can get to the same answer when solving a problem the world over.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Sure, I wasn't complaining :) I was merely making sure I understood what had been said.

Comment: oh and @Stephen even with just 4 operations you can have 24 different orders and potentially that many answers. all with the same numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In more formal notation, we'd not allow either expression.

The more formal notation in general is, given a set $X$ and a proposition $P$ of one variable:

$$\{x\in X: P(x)\}$$

So, for example, in your case:

$$\{k\in\mathbb N: \exists n\in \mathbb N(k=n^2)\}$$

Formal language is a mess sometimes, so for human readability purposes, we sometimes simplify.  For example, if the context is clear, we might write the above as:

$$\{k:\exists n (k=n^2)\}$$

That is, technically, ambiguous, but the context of the discussion might make it clear.

We can also say $\{n^2:n\in \mathbb N\}$. This is shorthand, but it is fairly direct shorthand.

The key to the notation, then, is that the left side before the $:$ separator is describing the elements. It is giving an "example" element a name, and then giving additional conditions after the $:$. But the stuff after the $:$ doesn't "change the value" on the left side of the $:$ - it is not a map, it is a filter, eliminating some of the possible values.

In English, we'd read $\{x\in X:P(x)\}$ as "The set of $x$ in $X$ such that $P(x)$ is true."

In English, we'd read $\{n^2:n\in\mathbb N\}$ as "The set of $n^2$ such that $n$ is a natural number."

Your sentence for $\{n\in\mathbb N: n^2\}$ is not in that form - it is not a "such that" expression, but a "followed by some operation applied to $n$." That is not how the notation is used.

Comment: Great, this clears a lot of my confusion. Should I read the bit in the brackets, $(k=n^2)$ $ $, as "*where* k=n^2"?

Comment: $\exists n(P(n))$ is read as "There exists $n$ such that $P(n)$.

Answer (score 2):

All forms of this notation are of the form

$$ \{ \text{term denoting an element of the set} \mid \text{additional information} \} $$

You have the pieces the other way around, which is why it's gramatically incorrect.

---

There are two primary ways this notation is used; the first is to pick out the elements of some set satisfying a property. For example, the set of integer square roots of $9$ would be written as

$$ \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n^2 = 9 \} $$

The key elements are, on the left hand side, we introduce the variable $n$ which refers to an arbitrary element of the set, along with specifying its *type*: that $n$ is a *natural number*. (there are various reasons why we do this on the left hand side rather than the right)

On the right hand side, we put down the condition that $n$ must obey to be an element of the set we construct.

The other way to use this notation is by applying a *transformation* to elements of some set. For example, the set of all integer multiples of $2$ is

$$ \{ 2n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$

In this usage, the variable $n$ is introduced on the right hand side, and is expressing an arbitrary element of the *domain* we are applying the transformation to. The left hand side denotes the element of the set we are constructing that corresponds to the element $n$ from the domain.

Comment: Great addition.  The inclusion of a domain makes it much clearer for me.   Just one little technicality.  You wrote "the set of integer square root**s** of 9".  But, by definition, isn't there only one single square root of 9? namely $\sqrt{9}$ (i.e., 3)?  I suspect you meant "the integer solution set of $n^2 - 9=0$".

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a set, and $\varphi$ is a function mapping an element $a \in A$ to a statement $\varphi(a)$ about $a$ that is either true or false, then we denote the set of all $a \in A$ such that the corresponding $\varphi(a)$ is true as 
$$\{ a \in A | \varphi(a) \}.$$
So in the definition, the order matters. First we see a dummy variable $a$ for the elements of $A$, and after the $|$ sign we get a statement about this $a$. 
Now if we take $A=\mathbb{N}$, then you are basically giving $\varphi$ as $\varphi(n)=n^2$. But *numbers aren't statements*. For example, how could we check whether $25$, which is $\varphi(5)$, is true? It is simply not a meaningful question, $25$ is not true or false. 
Now the notation $\{n^2  | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is another way of writing the image of the function from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself given by $n \mapsto n^2$. I have to recognize this last mentioned notation is a little bit abusive, since "the set of all $n^2$ such that $n \in \mathbb{N}$" is a an awkward sentence, because strictly speaking you don't know what set $n$ or $n^2$ is in until after the 'such that'.

Comment: Great, thanks.  It appears, in my textbook, I missed the part that the RHS of |  should be a statement, which is in fact the root of much of the confusion.  I also understand the abusion of the notation to allow a simple expression for sets such as the set of perfect squares.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a condition after the colon (read as "such that") which limits the set, for example $\{n \in \mathbb N : \sqrt{n} \in \mathbb N \}$ is ok.

Your example was like saying

> find all $n$ where $n \times n$

Where $n \times n$ what? Is less than some value? Is equal to some value? Is an element of a set?

Comment: That gives the wrong result. The OP is trying to describe the set of all squares of natural numbers, including $1$.

Comment: I read it as asking about set builder notation in general, updated to reflect your comment

Answer (score 0):

What does "The set of natural numbers such that each natural number is multiplied to itself." mean? That would mean:

> "The set of natural numbers...

OK, at this point, you should have $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ in your imagination.

> such that each natural number is multiplied to itself."

OK, now look for the numbers in the list above that are "multiplied to itself", and only keep those numbers. But I don't know what that would mean. Is $3$ "multiplied to itself"? You could do that I guess. Then all the the numbers in this list qualify, and they are all part of the set you are describing, and you end up with $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, not $\{1,4,9,\ldots\}$.

I think maybe you are thinking of a different English construction that would be more like "Take the set of natural numbers, then multiply each such number by itself." But that is not what set-builder notation conventionally means.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm what everybody else has said, after the colon, you need a *sentence* that may or may not be true. Since there’s no verb in what follows the colon, your formulation is bad grammar.